# Index/Match with three criteria

Tags: arrays, excel

I have searched and searched and searched and searched, I can only find solutions for index/match with two criteria.

does anyone have a solution for index/match with three criteria?

as a sample of my actual data, i would like to index/match the year, type and name to find the data in the month column

[image]

Comment: This was answered [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230390/automatically-fill-data-from-another-sheet/35230608#35230608) with two criteria it should not be hard to add a third.

Comment: Just noting that this question is asked a lot, but it's generated some nice learning points below. Thanks!

Comment: not true, very hard to add on a third if you didnt know it took the & to add on another condition in the array

Comment: Well now you have three answers to pick from.  It is something only you can do.  Reward the one that you use.  They all will work.  Click on the green check mark by the answer you choose.  No one here will have their feelings hurt if they do not get chosen.

Comment: working on getting it working on my spreadsheet, havent nailed it down yet >.<

Comment: Fair enough.  All three are superb in their knowledge and I am sure any problems you are having they can rectify. Just do not forget to choose one.  It will close out the question as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match an unlimited number of criteria by using *SUMPRODUCT()* to find the proper row:

```
=INDEX(D2:D9,SUMPRODUCT((A2:A9=2015)*(B2:B9="Revenue")*(C2:C9="Name 1")*ROW(2:9))-1)
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

**Scott's comment is correct!**  The advantagesof the *SUMPRODUCT()* approach is that it is not an array formula and can be expanded to handle many criteria.  The disadvantage is that it will only work if there is **1** matching row. 
The use of *SUMPRODUCT()* is explained very well here:

[xlDynamic Paper](http://www.xldynamic.com/source/xld.SUMPRODUCT.html#format)

Comment: I'm not too familiar with `Sumproduct` (although admittedly, it looks to be an important and versatile function, so I should look into it more).  Are there any advantages over using that instead of the index/match? Or is it going to do the same, just another way to do so?

Comment: Sumproduct will work unless there is more than one match.  In this instance I believe it is safe. With three variables I would hope they would be unique.  But with MATCH it will only return the first if there are duplicates.  So you have a problem if the three do not create a unique key.

Comment: Working on only 1 match is a pro and con - if you want it to flag an error when there is a duplicate, then it becomes a feature, not a flaw. Otherwise, if you want it to pick up the FIRST match if there are multiples, use @Bruce Wayne's method INDEX/MATCH. Otherwise, if you want it to sum ALL matches, use SUMIFS.

Comment: i am very intrigued by the ROW(2:9) part, not sure i understand it, do you know of anywhere i could read up on what its doing so i can make it work in my actual file? =/

Comment: figured out the row thing, think this one may be my solution however i have thousands of rows to check and its done a great job at crashing my spreadsheet...

Answer (score 3):

Because your question has numerical data, you can simply use SUMIFS.

SUMIFS provides the sum from a particular range [column D in this case], where any number of other ranges of the same size [the other columns, in this case] each match a particular criteria. For text results, one of the other recommended solutions will be needed.

In addition to being a little cleaner, this has the attribute [could be good or bad depending on your needs] that it will pick up multiple rows of data if multiples exist, and sum them all. If you expect unique rows, that's bad, because it won't warn you there are multiples.

The formula in your case would be as follows [obviously, you should adjust the formulas to reference your ID cells, and pick up the appropriate columns]:

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,2015,B:B,"Revenue",C:C,"Name1"))
```

What this does is:

Sum column D, for each row where: (1) column A is the number 2015; (2) column B is the text "Revenue"; AND (3) column C is the word "Name1".

Answer (score 2):

If assuming your data starts in A1 ("Year") and goes to D15 ("????"), you can use this. You bascically just add your criteria with `&`, then when doing the `Match()` regions, connect their respective ranges with `&` as well.

`=Index(D2:D9,Match(A15&B15&C15,A2:A9&B2:B9&C2:C9,0))`

and enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd> and make the references absolute (i.e. `$D$2:$D$9`), I just didn't to keep the formula a little easier to read.

Comment: Big plus for the only solution that will work to return the first match where multiple returns are possible. The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) can also be used to return the row number to [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) and can be expanded to also return the *second, third*, etc.

Comment: @Jeeped - I need to learn `Aggregate()`, I keep seeing it in many of your answers and it looks pretty versatile.  Thanks for the tip!!