# index match with two requirements in the rows

Tags: excel

I am trying to do a table which isn't too far off [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230390/automatically-fill-data-from-another-sheet/35230608#35230608) previous question, but I can't quite get it to work.

I have a table on one sheet of the form

```
date type score type score type score ...
1    a    1.2   b    1     c    5 
2    b    5.6
3    a    3.6   c    1.6   d    4
...
```

And I am trying to get a formula to turn into the form

```
 date    type a    type b   type c    type d
 1       1.2       1        5
 2                 5.6
 3       3.6                1.6       4
```

I have tried using offset, and index/matching but I can't quite get there. Is anyone able to provide a formula to go on a different sheet which can do this? My types and dates will be changing constantly which is why I can just hard-code it.
Cheers!

edit:
The date column might not be in order in the first column which is why I am having issues. Thank you ImaginaryHuman072889 for your answer anyway. My data will look more like

```
date type score type score type score ...
1    a    1.2   b    1     c    5 
3    b    5.6
2    a    3.6   c    1.6   d    4
...
```

Comment: Just noticed your edit to this post now. See below, I edited my answer to account for this change. Just FYI for future reference: All necessary details about the problem such as this edit here should be included when you first post the problem rather than waiting for an answer and then editing your problem.

Comment: Also, if you edit your question, you should also post a comment on my answer letting me know. Only reason I even noticed that you edited this is because I happened to come back here and look at my answer again, but I didn't get a notification that you edited the post. If you would have commented on my answer, I would have been notified and could have responded here more quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formula works for me:

```
= IFERROR(INDEX($B2:$G2,MATCH(RIGHT(B$6,1),$B2:$G2,0)+1),"")
```

Of course, you will have to update this formula accordingly to include your specific cell ranges.

See below working example. I have this formula in cell `B7` and I dragged it over to cell `E9`.

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Just noticed your edit. This is possible but just makes the formula considerably longer.

See below, updated formula to take this into account (several line breaks added for readability):

```
= IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$G$4,MATCH($A7,$A$2:$A$4,0),
  INDEX(MMULT(($B$2:$G$4=RIGHT(B$6,1))+0,
  TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($B$2:$G$4)-MIN(COLUMN($B$2:$G$4))+1)),
  MATCH($A7,$A$2:$A$4,0))+1)+0,"")
```

Note this is an array formula, so you must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on your keyboard after pasting this formula instead of just pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

See below working example. I have this formula in cell `B7` and I dragged it over to cell `E9`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this!